# How to make two different backgrounds for topbar and main body of a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I have a topbar, i.e. something like Facebook or or StackExchange or Twitter's top portion of the screen, and I want it to have a different background than the rest of the page (the stuff below/the main body). How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the your header_block outside your wrapper

> ```
>  <div id="header_block">
>       ...... Header_block Contents
>     </div>
>    <div id="wrapper">
>       ...... Entire Page
>     </div>
> ```

css

> ```
>    #header_block
>      {
>            position:fixed;
>            width:100%;
>            float:left;
>       }
> ```

This should do the work

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

css

```
body { background:#252525; margin:0;padding:0;}
.headerStrip{ height:40px; width:100%; z-index:1001; background:#F00; position:absolute; position:fixed;}
```

Html : Put it after body tag

```
<div class="headerStrip"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code :

```
<div id="topbar">

</div>
```

and you can use `Position:fixed;` like twitter's topbar

```
body{
    background: green;
}

#topbar{
    width:100%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:80px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to accomplish this is to use the [CSS Background property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).

For example stackoverflow is using a div with an id like the following to set the background color for the gray bar up top:

```
<div id="custom-header"></div>
```

Then in their css file they are using background-color like this; note the height as well:

```
#custom-header {
background-color: #EEE; <------------
height: 31px;
margin-bottom: -31px;
}
```

This gives us the grey bar up top which passes behind the StackExchange logo.

You can see that the body is set to white via CSS and the Background (shorthand) property:

```
body {
background: white; <-------------
color: black;
font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
font-size: 80%;
text-align: center;
}
```

You can see that the footer div is taking it a step further by using background (shorthand) and border-top for the 7 pixel solid black line:

```
#footer {
color: #444;
background: #777; <------------
border-top: 7px solid black; <------------
clear: both;
padding: 15px;
margin-top: 30px;
}
```

This is a few years old now though, you might find value in running through some [tutorials like this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-builds/convert-a-warm-cheerful-web-design-to-html-and-css/) from Net Tuts.